# What is the difference between ElasticSearch API through 9300 vs 9200 port?

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert

I play with ElasticSearch REST API via 9200 port.

Official Java library client connect to 9300 port.

What is the difference between port API?

I want to pass logging events into ElasticSearch and look to Bulk API:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-bulk.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

What bother me the most is that Java API through `PreBuiltTransportClient` bring a lot of dependencies that is totally unnecessary overhead if plug Client into application (why I need `org.apache.lucene` jars in app??).

Is there any performance difference, do they provide same level of  reliability?

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html)

java client creates a transport node client for elastic and connects to cluster(not as fully functional node) through transport module instead of working neatly on 9200 port. So it fallbacks to port 9300 to connect to transport layer of ES.

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));
```

Elastic listen for all [transport](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) request at port 9300, even other nodes.

Comment: Do you mean that 9300 is a discovery and control port for cluster, while 9200 is public API port for requesting? I don't understand benefits from using Java Client for Bulk insert on 9300 port instead of REST on 9200.

Comment: 9200 is rest http port for elastic, yeah 9300 is both discovery and transport module port. for bulk indexing maybe it helps in better performance as it get to connect to data nodes directly for importing data to cluster  than sending bulk data through http port. C# client for elastic also works the save as java by creating a virtual transport client node.

Comment: Details on the discovery process are available in the Elasticsearch documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/modules-discovery-hosts-providers.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java, you can use the [Transport Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/7.14/java-api.html) to talk to Elasticsearch on port 9300 using the binary protocol. The Transport Client is now deprecated - you should use the [REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html) anyway because it has better backwards compatibility and there's no significant performance benefit anyway.